# Elastic Transcoder - MPEG Dash output - tutorials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I use AWS Elastic Encoder to encode to HLS (with success), and have been trying to get the same mp4 files transcoded to play in MPEG-Dash.

When I transcode into HLS, I typically choose 30 sec segments, and for a 5 min video, I get 12 files and a playlist (using one of the built in presets)

When I transcode same file into MPEG-Dash (using 30 second segments) - I still get one large file. No segments. And no audio. The playlist format seems to be ok - in .mpd format. I am using a built in preset.

Am I supposed to do TWO transcodes for every mpeg-dash transcode? One in video, and the other in audio, with a playlist to tie the two together?

Is there an online tutorial which outlines how to encode into MPEG-Dash format?

Or what do most of you use?

Comment: Having the same issue. Another thing, unlike HLS, when you create a MPEG Dash job, you dont see the segment filename preview. So maybe an issue with Amazon's implementation

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, selecting DASH preset doesn't create more than one segment file.

Comment: It is 2020 and nothing changed...

Answer (score 0):

use mediaconvert to get more than one file segment

this is result using mediaconvert
[image]